# Lifetime of values stored in $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

I wanted to know what is the lifetime of the values stored in $rootScope especially in cases when the page is opened in a different tab.Whether the value gets lost or will it be retained in the newly opened tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean a different tab in your browser, no variable is shared at all, unless you use `localStorage` (which is not something related to Angularjs).

If you are using tabs designed in some application of yours, they should share `$rootScope` and all of its variables.